# Data transfer from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

How can I get the browser's height and width to PHP? Like a data transfer from JavaScript to PHP?
With using `innerHeight` and `InnerWidth`, I think.

(I just need to show user small picture if he has small screensize and big if big and without a data about screensize I can't do it)

I have like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slideshow.css" type="text/css" /> 

<script> 
  document.write('script.php?screen=' + screen.width + 'x' + screen.height'); 
</script> 

</head> 
<body> 

  <?php $lol=$_GET['screen']; 
  <?php echo "SIZE : $lol" ?> 

</body> 
</html>
```

And it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to make an AJAX call from JavaScript to a PHP script. That PHP script would save the screen resolution in the current session (you'll need to use sessions for this). A PHP script requested at a later point could then access the screen resolution as passed by the JavaScript snippet.

Comment: I'm so bad in AJAX. It could be done just with javascript and php. When they are on the same page.

Comment: @Trava no, it can't be done without Ajax, sorry. Javascript runs after PHP has generated the page, and has no chance of passing anything back to PHP. This is why Ajax exists.

Comment: @Trava check out jQuery's Ajax examples: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ it's easy to get into, just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know AJAX then you can use links to send information to the server with the GET method.

```
<script language="javascript">
   function load(){
      document.getElementById('myAnchor').href="test2.php?sw="+screen.width+"&sh="+screen.height;
   }
</script>
<body onload="load();">
<a id="myAnchor" href="#">Send to server</a>
<?php
if (isset($_GET)){
    print_r($_GET);
}
?> 
</body>
```

Or you can also use forms to send information to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a smple ajax object without using any library.

http://www.pagecolumn.com/javascript/ajax_object.htm

In client side, use it like,

```
function foo() {
    var screen=' + screen.width + 'x' + screen.height'; 
    ajax.getRequest("test_get.php",["screen"], [screen],function(data){
       alert(data);
    });
}
```

In PHP,

```
<?php $lol=$_GET['screen']; 
 echo "SIZE : $lol"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on your **web server**.
The PHP processor outputs HTML, which is transmitted to the client **browser**.
-- at this point PHP is *finished*. It *can't do anything else*.
The browser now interprets the HTML page and executes the javascript - *on the client machine*.

The Javascript **can't** pass a value to the PHP because

- The PHP is on the *server* while the javascript is on the *client*
- The PHP has *finished* running by the time the javascript *starts* running

As other people have mentioned, the best you can do at this point is pass the height/width information back to the server to be used later *or* make an AJAX call to update the page dynamically given the size information.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen resolution, but with JavaScript *NOT* PHP.  PHP is server-side.  However, you can have a JavaScript pass values to PHP using ajax or any other method.

Comment: Ok, i need a data transfer from javascript to php)