# How do I show my script value from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php

**I have a script (*javascript*)**

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".editagunan").click(function(){
        var id_agunan = $(this).attr("data_id_agunan"); 

        $("#value_id_agunan").val(id_agunan);

        $("#myModalEdit").modal("show");
    });
});
</script>
```

**how to display 'value_id_agunan' from javascript to php**

```
<?php echo id="value_id_agunan" ?>
```

**but the script is wrong, how to fix ? Thanks**

Comment: Give a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072817/data-transfer-from-javascript-to-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data transfer from JavaScript to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072817/data-transfer-from-javascript-to-php)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you are asking on how to write html inside a php file.

Just write HTML directly, like this:

```
<p id="value_id_agunan"></p>
```

If you want to show the above html code on some condition then use php like this:

```
<?php if(showParagraph){ /* some variable */ ?>
    <p id="value_id_agunan"></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: does not working, but it can work if using form `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_agunan" id="value_id_agunan" >`